# Quotient involving $\pi$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ is a finite group and $\pi$ be a set of primes. Suppose that $P$ is a normal $\pi$-subgroup. Is it true that the quotient group $G/P$ is $\pi$-group?

I know that since $P$ is a $\pi$-subgroup, each of the primes dividing $|P|$ are in $\pi$. Also if $p||P|$ then $p||G|$ but I'm unable to get any conclusion after this.

Comment: What's a $\pi-$group?

Comment: A group that has order which is a $\pi$-number

Comment: Wikipedia says: "If $\pi$ is a set of primes, then a Hall $\pi$-subgroup is a subgroup whose order is a product of primes in $\pi$, and whose index is not divisible by any primes in $\pi$," and coprimality is baked into the definition. Is it not, for your definition of a $\pi$-subgroup?

Comment: Yes. A $\pi$-subgroup is a group whose order is a product of primes in $\pi$ i.e. a $\pi$-number. Now $|G/P| = [G :P]$ and I only know that $P$ is just a normal $\pi$-subgroup of G and not a Hall $\pi$-subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not true in general. If $G$ is a $\pi$-group, then any subgroup or quotient is a $\pi$-group as well. This follows easily from Lagrange's Theorem. But if you require a normal subgroup $P$ to be a $\pi$-group, then $|G:P|$ could miss some primes. For example, take $G=S_3$ and $P=A_3$. Then $P$ is a 3-group, but the quotient is certainly not.